# How to turn nested loops into list comprehension that keep track of inner loop?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Is there a way to make this list comprehension to produce the wanted output like I written down ?

```
year_diff = [(1-(np.absolute(x-y)/2005)) for x in excluded_books_over10['yearOfPublication'] for y in years]
```

Output:

```
[0.999002493765586, 0.9980049875311721, 0.9940149625935162, 0.9980049875311721, 0.9955112219451372, 0.9980049875311721, 0.999002493765586, 0.9995012468827931, 0.9985037406483791, 0.9965087281795512, 1.0, 0.9985037406483791, 0.9925187032418953, 0.9995012468827931, 0.9950124688279302, 0.9960099750623441, 0.9985037406483791, 0.9955112219451372, 0.999002493765586, 0.9995012468827931, 0.9995012468827931, 0.9970074812967581, 0.9985037406483791, 0.9980049875311721, 0.9925187032418953, 0.9945137157107232, 0.9915211970074813, 0.9940149625935162, 0.9875311720698254, 0.9955112219451372, 0.9955112219451372, 0.9975062344139651, 0.9970074812967581, 1.0, 0.9900249376558603,....
```

This code produce the result that I want.

```
new_list = []
for x in excluded_books_over10['yearOfPublication']:
    temp_list = []
    for y in years:
        temp_list.append(1-(np.absolute(x-y)/2005))
    new_list.append(temp_list)
print(new_list)
```

Output :

```
[[0.999002493765586, 0.999002493765586], [0.9980049875311721, 1.0], [0.9940149625935162, 0.9960099750623441], [0.9980049875311721, 1.0], [0.9955112219451372, 0.9975062344139651], [0.9980049875311721, 1.0], [0.999002493765586, 0.999002493765586], [0.9995012468827931, 0.9975062344139651], [0.9970074812967581, 0.999002493765586], [0.9985037406483791, 0.9995012468827931], [0.9965087281795512, 0.9985037406483791], [1.0, 0.9980049875311721], [0.9985037406483791, 0.9995012468827931], [0.9925187032418953, 0.9945137157107232], [0.9995012468827931, 0.9985037406483791], [0.9950124688279302, 0.9970074812967581], [0.9960099750623441, 0.9980049875311721], [0.9985037406483791, 0.9995012468827931], [0.9955112219451372, 0.9975062344139651], [0.999002493765586, 0.999002493765586], [0.9995012468827931, 0.9985037406483791], [0.9995012468827931, 0.9985037406483791], [0.9970074812967581, 0.999002493765586], [0.9985037406483791, 0.9995012468827931], ...
```

Thanks everyone in advance and feel free to edit if I have done something wrong.

Solution by Swazy :

```
year_diff = [[(1-(np.absolute(x-y)/2005)) for y in years] for x in excluded_books_over10['yearOfPublication']]
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code/data? You seem to be mixing NumPy and plain Python lists, which certainly isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should produce the output you are after:

```
year_diff = [[(1-(np.absolute(x-y)/2005)) for y in years] for x in excluded_books_over10['yearOfPublication']]
```

Comment: Could you tell me how this works? I mean what's the concept behind putting the inner loop first? Also thank you that works as I wanted!

Comment: Glad I could help! The solution is a list comprehension within a list comprehension. The form of the desired output was lists over years within a list over publication years so you need to have the years loop first.

By the way - I don't think you've copied the solution quite right above!

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes I've changed now it's fine!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only need an extra square bracket around your first for loop as shown below, let me know if this works.

```
year_diff = [[(1-(np.absolute(x-y)/2005)) for x in excluded_books_over10['yearOfPublication']] for y in years]
```

Comment: No that doesn't work the way I want to, it's making a list into a list with all the numbers inside, Swazy solution is that I was looking for, thank you anyway!